# Android Connection Service, call is not permitted

Tags: java, android

I am implementing Connection Service in a mobile VoIP application. After using the application for a while and creating calls using placeCall or addNewIncomingCall, creating new calls is no longer possible, but after relaunch application everything works again for a while. After calling any of the mentioned methods, here is what I have in logcat:

```
2023-10-19 15:13:47.363 23963-23963 TelecomFramework I  : createConnectionFailed TC@270: (TSI.pC->CIP.sNOCI)->CS.crCoF->H.CS.crCoF(cast)@E-Kdk
2023-10-19 15:13:47.364 23963-23963 TelecomFramework I  TelecomConnectionService: createConnectionFailed TC@270: (TSI.pC->CIP.sNOCI)->CS.crCoF->H.CS.crCoF(cast)@E-Kdk
```

isIncomingCallPermitted and isOutgoingCallPermitted return false. According to the documentation, false is returned in cases:

- PhoneAccount does not have property PhoneAccount#CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED set (i.e. it is a managed ConnectionService), and the active or held call limit has been reached.
- There is an ongoing emergency call.

I create Phone Account in such a way, as you can see the `CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED` flag is set. In any case, at first everything works correctly.

```java
private static PhoneAccount createAccount(Context context) {
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            TelecomConnectionService.class.getName());
    PhoneAccountHandle accountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(componentName, context.getPackageName());
    String identity = "sip:app@example.com";
    Uri address = Uri.parse(identity);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putBoolean(PhoneAccount.EXTRA_SUPPORTS_HANDOVER_TO, true);
    extras.putBoolean(PhoneAccount.EXTRA_LOG_SELF_MANAGED_CALLS, true);
    extras.putBoolean(PhoneAccount.EXTRA_ALWAYS_USE_VOIP_AUDIO_MODE, true);

    PhoneAccount.Builder builder = PhoneAccount.builder(accountHandle, context.getPackageName())
            .addSupportedUriScheme(PhoneAccount.SCHEME_SIP)
            .setAddress(address)
            .setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_SELF_MANAGED)
            .setExtras(extras);

    return builder.build();
}
```

I terminate connections by calling the `destroyConnection` method in `onStateChanged` when state is equal to `Connection.STATE_DISCONNECTED`

Implementation of `destroyConnection`:

```java
public void destroyConnection() {
    Log.d(TAG, "destroyConnection");
    TelecomConnectionService.destroyCurrentConnection();
    super.destroy();
}
```

and `destroyCurrentConnection` is simply:

```java
public static void destroyCurrentConnection() {
    conn = null;
}
```

Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Could it be that you reached "the active or held call limit has been reached"?

Comment: good question, but I can't find anything about this limit in the documentation. Additionally, just resetting the app is enough to get everything working properly. Also strange is that the number of connections I can create before this problem occurs is different every time.

Comment: I think that the fact that when restarting the application, everything works is a good indication that that is the issue here. The amount of connections may be different every time might be based on some internal OS decision making.